Azure Boards Workflow Sequencing
Been doing research into replacing Jira with Azure Boards. One of the ways that Azure Boards comes up short so far is that it seems that I am unable to set up workflow sequencing with the sprint columns.
I was able to set up workflow sequencing with the workflow state with the process type rules under the collection settings, but this bound the states only and not the associated columns. When attempting to move a card to an incorrect state, instead of preventing the move it was cause an error that would have to be corrected before moving the card to a correct state.
I also tested a plugin from the marketplace, but this didn't seem to change anything and after reading some, it appears that it wasn't even designed to do what I needed anyway and does the same thing as the rules when it is working.
Is column workflow sequencing just not a thing in Azure Boards or am I missing something?


I was able to set up workflow sequencing with the workflow state with the process type rules under the collection settings, but this bound the states only and not the associated columns. When attempting to move a card to an incorrect state, instead of preventing the move it was cause an error that would have to be corrected before moving the card to a correct state.

In Azure Boards, workflow sequencing is more closely associated with work item states than with the columns on the board. Setting up workflow sequencing through the process type rules under collection settings binds only to the states, not the columns. Thus, moving a card to an incorrect state won't be prevented but will result in an error. However, when changing a work item's state, the restricted states will not be displayed as options. This is a feature in Azure Boards.
Maybe this feature doesn't fully meet your needs. You can request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

Unfortunately, after much research on both our end and our provider's end, this is indeed the answer. Fortunately, this is more of an important want than a hard and fast need. I will submit that request to Microsoft and explain the situation to management.

It does seem that the state transition when the cards are moved indicates to me that this is a bug or a partially implemented feature.

Yes, by default. Azure DevOps does not restrict the moving between states. The teams should follow dev process principles. However, you can create some restrictions on the process level with rules: Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)
Example:


Unfortunately, I had tried that earlier. It does restrict the state itself. The issue in question is that it doesn't restrict the movement of cards in between the columns in the sprint view.
